# Child View Controller loses delegate after Presenting and Dismissing Modal View

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, presentviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I am adding a Child View Controller using this code:

```
MyCustomViewController * overlayView = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCustom" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *parentViewController = self.tabBarController;
[modalView willMoveToParentViewController:parentViewController];

// set the frame for the overlayView
overlayView.view.frame = parentViewController.view.frame;

[parentViewController.view addSubview: overlayView.view];

[parentViewController.view needsUpdateConstraints];
[parentViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];

// Finish adding the overlayView as a Child View Controller
[parentViewController addChildViewController: overlayView];
[overlayView didMoveToParentViewController:parentViewController];
```

Then within `MyCustomViewController` a button tap triggers a modal view to be presented:

```
MyModalViewController *vc = [[MyModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DirectEmployerSignup" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(closeTheModal:)];
vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Tapping the `UIBarButtonItem` triggers `closeTheModal:`

```
- (void)closeTheModal:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

After the modal closes, `MyCustomViewController` is still visible, but the view stops reacting as expected. The `UITextViews` on `MyCustomViewController` do not trigger their delegate methods in `MyCustomViewController.m`, etc.

**For Clarity:** I can still tap into the `UITextFields` on `MyCustomViewController`, and can still see the buttons react when I tap them, but they are not triggering their associated `IBActions`, etc.

Any thoughts about what is going on would be very appreciated.

**Additional Info**
I added a method to close the modal, using `[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` in `MyModalViewController` and pointed the `action:@selector()` to the method.

The method in `MyModalViewController` fires and closes the modal, but `MyCustomViewController` is still not responding.

**po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]**
When I run `po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]`, before the Modal view is presented, I see this:

```
<UINavigationController 0x7fc23985b200>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fc238f3b760>
   | <MyTabBarController 0x7fc23a045400>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fc238cc7500>
   |    | <MyNavigationController 0x7fc23985a800>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fc23b0497e0>
   |    |    | <FirstTabViewController 0x7fc238d47650>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fc23b1318a0>
   |    | <UINavigationController 0x7fc23a0bc000>, state: disappeared, view:  (view not loaded)
   |    |    | <SecondTabViewController 0x7fc238c8da90>, state: disappeared, view:  (view not loaded)
   |    | <UINavigationController 0x7fc23987c800>, state: disappeared, view:  (view not loaded)
   |    |    | <ThirdTabViewController 0x7fc238f77c00>, state: disappeared, view:  (view not loaded)
   |    | <MyCustomViewController 0x7fc238d48e50>, state: appearing, view: <UIView 0x7fc23b086220>
```

But... After I dismiss the Modal and re-run `po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]`, the `<MyCustomViewController 0x7fc238d48e50>` is missing.

Maybe the problem stems from the fact that `<MyCustomViewController>` says "appearing" and does not say "appeared" ?

My Solution
I changed `MyCustomViewController` from

`UIViewController *parentViewController = self.tabBarController;`

to

`UIViewController *parentViewController = self.tabBarController.navigationController;`

Thanks to everyone that helped. I will review your answers with hopes I can accomplish this effect better next time.

Comment: You are not adding the controller correctly, you shouldn't be calling `didMoveToParentViewController` manually when adding.

Comment: What happens when you log `allTargets` on your buttons? Are your actions still properly attached to buttons? Are there any warnings/errors in your console? What happens when you log controller hierarchy after dismissing (`[[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]`)?

Comment: Logging `[_theButton allTargets]` produces the same result before and after the Modal: `<MyCustomViewController: 0x7fbb629a1e20>`.

Not sure about `_printHierarchy`, trying to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Usually from the debugger with the `po` (print object) command.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for your help. Just added some info about `_printHierarchy` to the original post.

Comment: It's impossible for me to reproduce the issue. I can seethere are things that shouldn't be happening but none of them is causing your issue for me. My child controller is always in `disappeared` state and it is never removed from the tab bar controller. I would recommend you to check all `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear` and  `viewDidDisappear` and see if you are not doing something wrong there, e.g. removing the controller from the hierarchy. I can confirm that when the controller is removed from hierarchy, actions on its view won't be delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that your `MyCustomViewController` got removed from its parent controller. Your events stop being delivered then.

From the code you have posted I cannot say what got the controller removed but you should be able to debug it pretty easily using a breakpoint in `-[MyCustomViewController removeFromParentViewController]:` You are either removing it explicitly by mistake or `UITabBarController` removes it by itself (could be caused by the issue described below).

However, there is another big issue:

`UITabBarController` is a container controller. The whole point of the controller is to manage its child view controllers. That also means that the controller is managing which controller is receiving appearance callbacks (e.g. `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:` and so on). By adding another child view controller you are doing something that is not supported.

For example, when `UITabBarController` appears, it sends `viewDidAppear:` only to its selected controller. It does not send `viewDidAppear:` to your additional controller.

That can lead to many very problematic states and I think this is the root of your problem.

Instead of adding a child controller directly to a `UITabBarController`, you can consider the following hierarchy (introducing a common parent for tab bar controller and your custom controller).

```
UIViewController
   |  UITabBarController
   |  MyCustomViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are dismissing the `navigationController` within the modal... otherwise it's just dismissing the internal controller (not it's parent!) and still be present (and intercepting your events)

```
- (void)closeTheModal:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Would this need to go in `MyModalViewController`? Doesn't work from `MyCustomViewController`. Any way to execute it from `MyCustomViewController` ?

Comment: I added a method in `MyModalViewController` and pointed the `action:@selector()` to the method. The method in `MyModalViewController` fires and closes the modal, but `MyCustomViewController` is still not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this code

```
MyModalViewController *vc = [[MyModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DirectEmployerSignup" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(closeTheModal:)];
vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When you are declaring,

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(closeTheModal:)];
vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
```

the target set is `self`, as you are declaring it in `MyCustomViewController`, the self will be a `MyCustomViewController` instance. And may be you have declared the selector `closeTheModal` in same class. Thus the instance released with self may be `MyCustomViewController` insatnce.

Do this,

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:**vc** action:@selector(closeTheModal:)];
vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
```

And declare the selector in `MyModalViewController` class and check.